# What are the negatives of using external content type- external list approach to manage master data stored in on premise SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2013, office365

For one of the client who wants to manage the master data for a DW using SharePoint Online, I've created an `External content type` on the DB table on an on-premise SQL sserver using a Secure Store service target application. This `external content type` is consumed by an `external list` with default CRUD forms and list views.

In my opinion this works very well.

**But I want to be very sure that there are no  caveats associated with this approach.**

And what are the factors which may possibly rule out using this approach in lieu of some other DB connector like Layer2? (I am wondering about scalability of the ECT-External list solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically MSN has not provided support for ECT over on-premise SQL server to O365 SharePoint Online.
However the on-premise SQL server still works(just like Azure SQL) provided that:

1. On premise SQL server being used is the default instance.
2. SQL service is running on default ports and not on custom ports.

Both the above limitations are imposed due to the handling/storage of connection string in SharePoint Online ECT schema. This does not allow special characters like `/` or `:` in it.